# php createimage does not output an image to browser

Tags: php

can you help?

Using XAMPP I have localhost/drawrectangle.php containing the following code which does not render an image, ll I get is an image placeholder, can you help?

```
<?php

// Create a 200 x 200 image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

// Allocate colors
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);

// Draw three rectangles each with its own color
imagerectangle($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 150, $pink);
imagerectangle($canvas, 45, 60, 120, 100, $white);
imagerectangle($canvas, 100, 120, 75, 160, $green);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);

?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you get?

Comment: right click placeholder, "save image", then load the file into a text/hex editor and see what's really in there. if you have any php errors/warnings being output, they'll be embedded at the start of the image data and cause it to be treated as corrupted.

Comment: ["Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent..."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: @DOCASAREL That's actually the case.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - If he hasn't got any whitespaces before the actual php code.

Comment: I see, you took the whole example from the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php. I am sorry, just wanted to help. I have no experience with `imagerectangle`. How does it get output anyway?

Comment: ... Seems to work fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/PPP1Na2.png

Comment: @KristerAndersson If there was any output before header(), PHP would throw an error.

Comment: You should check here and output it http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) "Note: JPEG support is only available if PHP was compiled against GD-1.8 or later."

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the GD library (php extension) enabled?

Comment: GD library is enabled according to phpinfo

Comment: Is there any white space before the <?php tag ?

Comment: there is no white space bfore the <?php tag....

Comment: I previously had WAMP installed and had the same issue, so tried XAMPP but still no joy, have the same problem

Comment: If you get a placeholder (I assume you mean "broken image") You should replace `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` with `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`. Most probably you'll get an error message.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider

heres some of my output

�����JFIF���������>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality
���C�  

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342���C   

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222�������"�������������� 
�������}�!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz����������������������������������������������������������������������������������� 
������w�!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�
$4�

Comment: @DOCASAREL how do i find out which version of GD library i have installed?

Comment: `var_dump(gd_info());`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php.

Comment: @DOCASAREL  JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support -> 
array(12) { ["GD Version"]=> string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)" ["FreeType Support"]=> bool(true) ["FreeType Linkage"]=> string(13) "with freetype" ["T1Lib Support"]=> bool(false) ["GIF Read Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Create Support"]=> bool(true) ["JPEG Support"]=> bool(true) ["PNG Support"]=> bool(true) ["WBMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["XPM Support"]=> bool(true) ["XBM Support"]=> bool(true) ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: That says `["GD Version"]=> string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)` and should so far work.

Comment: Indeed it should but still no joy. I'm at a loss! :(